# How to stop clipping of NSString drawAtPoint: withAttributes: in a UIView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

How does one use drawAtPoint: withAttributes within an instance of a UIView subclass so that the text drawn on the screen can be seen outside of the frame of the UIView subclass instance?
My use of [self setClipsToBounds:NO] within the subclass of the UIView is resulting in clipping of the text along the frame of the view.

The UIView subclass I am using, WordView.m:

```
#import "WordView.h"

@implementation WordView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [self setClipsToBounds:NO];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [@"Hello World" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) withAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:
                                                            [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40],
                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor] }];

}

@end
```

I am creating the WordView in the viewWillAppear stage of the ViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    WordView *wordView = [[WordView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 40)];

    [self.view addSubview:wordView];

}
```

Comment: Try using a `UILabel` subview instead of drawing the text in `drawRect:`.

Comment: @rmaddy -Thank you. Your suggestion works, but I still want to know how to do this with the drawAtPoint: withAttributes: method, or if it isn't possible, I want to understand why.